# Decision Tree Problems to solve

Tags: data-structures, decision-tree

I have an exam on data structures and I've been looking all over the place for problems that are solved using decision trees (sorting n elements in minimum of nlog n W.C).
If somebody can provide me with sources for such questions I will be happy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, let's consider the case when you have to guess a number between 1 and 1024 and whenever you guess, there are two possibilities:

1. You guessed it right.
2. You guessed it wrong.

In case of 1., the algorithm finishes, as you have found the answer. In case of 2., you have a further decision:

2.1. The number you are searching for is smaller than your guess
2.2. The number you are searching for is greater than your guess

So, if you model the binary search, then your work will be VERY simple, as you will repeat the very same idea for a finite number of times. Read more about Binary Search here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm